# How to run Rscript with VBA (Excel Macro) if I don't have admin access on the computer

Tags: r, vba, excel

I am writing this code in a Macro:

```
Sub RunRscript()

Dim shell As Object
Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
Dim style As Integer: style = 1
Dim errorCode As Integer
Dim abc,xyz As Double
'Dim Folder As String
abc = Range("B2").Value
xyz = Range("B3").Value
'Folder = Range("B9").Value
Dim path As String
path = "RScript C:\Users\727709\Desktop\Trial\tradex2.R" & Chr(34) & abc & Chr(34) & xyz    
errorCode = shell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)

End Sub
```

I am getting this error:

```
Run-time error '-2147024894 (80070002)
Method 'Run' of object 'IWshShell3' failed.
```

I tried and looked for a solution to the problem and most probably it is happening because I don't have admin rights on the system. Can someone please assist me in finding a solution?

Comment: Have you included the path of rscript.exe in the `PATH` environment variable? And is the script you're running in the current user's desktop? If not, then the script may be inaccessible. If yes, see first question.

Comment: Rscript.exe is in C folder. cant move it from there to anywhere else as i dont have admin rights.

Comment: The command line you are executing will be something like `RScript C:\Users\727709\Desktop\Trial\tradex2.R"123"456` (assuming cell B2 contained `123` and B3 contained `456`).  It seems strange that there is no space between the `.R` and the double-quote mark or after the second double-quote mark.

Comment: Chr(34) is equivalent to " ". hence used that instead of going with space.its not throwing any error for that

Comment: Chr(34) is equivalent to a double-quotation mark (i.e. `"`).  Chr(32) is a space.  Change your code to `path = "RScript C:\Users\727709\Desktop\Trial\tradex2.R " & abc & " " & xyz` (or, if you don't like having spaces for some reason, use `path = "RScript" & Chr(32) & "C:\Users\727709\Desktop\Trial\tradex2.R" & Chr(32) & abc & Chr(32) & xyz`)

Comment: If you place a `MsgBox path` line after your `path = ...` line you can check that it is producing what you wanted.

Comment: thanks. Let me check.

Comment: you're right. Changed it to Chr(32). :)

But it still throwing same issue as before.

Comment: Try running that exact statement (as displayed by the MsgBox I suggested you place in the code) within a normal command window - does it work there?

Comment: OK, if I use a command (i.e. a value of `path`) of simply `"Cmd"` it successfully opens a command window.  If I use a command of `"""C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe"""` it successfully invokes WordPad.  So it seems like there is some issue with the command you are using.  Is `RScript` definitely "findable" in the default paths?

Comment: I have to call it a night now - if anyone else notices this thread, please add your suggestions.

Comment: Not asking you to move it somewhere else. Make sure its path is included in the PATH environment variable of Windows. And you didn't answer if the script you're trying to run is in that path you specified in your code and if it's accessible. If it's in another user account's folder, you won't have access to it because the user account you're using isn't an administrator.

Comment: @RowenChumacera no path is different. Reason being my R.exe. file is in path C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\bin but i cant copy my  Rscript tradex2.R there as admin rights doesnt allow me to copy it there.

Comment: @RowenChumacera  its running now sucessfuly if i am giving path as 
path = """C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\bin\RScript"" C:\Users\727709\Desktop\Trial\tradex2.R"   but now i am unable to pass variable from excel